# What is the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{p^2}{(p^2+4)^2}$

Tags: laplace-transform

Given $$f(p)=\dfrac{p^2}{(p^2+4)^2}$$

So $$f(p)=\dfrac{p^2}{(p^2+4)^2}=\dfrac{p^2+4-4}{(p^2+4)^2}=\frac{1}{p^2+4}-\frac{4}{(p^2+4)^2}$$

I know the inverse Laplace transform of the first term but stuck on the second term. How can I do this? Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F(s)=\frac{s^2}{(s^2+4)^2}=s\frac{d}{ds}((\frac{1}{s^2+4})\times\frac1{2})$$

$$f(t)=\frac{d}{dt}(t\times(\frac{\sin(2t)}{2}\times\frac1{2}))=\frac1{4}(\sin(2t)+2t\cos(2t))$$

Comment: NIce. One more thing please explain a little about that $s$ vanishes in the third step

Comment: $$L[\frac{d f(t)}{dt}]=sF(s)$$
$$L[t f(t)]=\frac{d F(s)}{ds}$$

Comment: $s$ is converted to derivative in time domain. While $\frac{d}{ds}$ is converted into $t$.

Comment: Got it. Nice ..

Comment: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=InverseLaplaceTransform[s^2%2F%28s^2%2B4%29^2])